# How to test if Google PageSpeed module is working correctly?

Tags: google

Say someone installs Google PageSpeed module [as described here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download):

```
sudo touch /etc/default/mod-pagespeed
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

How can you test if it's working? I didn't see any test command in the linked documentation above. There are some "test files" but it is unclear to me from this documentation how are these used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this quickly on the command line by running curl against your server with the -I option which will just print the headers and the -s option to prevent the connection info from being displayed. Then we send it to grep to see if there is an X-Mod-Pagespeed header.

```
curl -Is http://IP.AD.DR.ES/ | grep X-Mod-Pagespeed
```

if you want to make this easier to use you could use the following shell script which takes a server as the first parameter and a string to match in the output as the second.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

HEADERS=$(curl -Is $1)
RETURN=1

echo "Fetched these headers from $1":
echo "$HEADERS"

if [[ $( echo "$HEADERS" | grep $2) ]]
then
    echo "$1 returns the $2 header"
    RETURN=0
else
    echo "$2 header not found"
    RETURN=1
fi

exit $RETURN
```

You can then run it as

```
script http://server/ X-Mod-Pagespeed
```

adjust the return values to suit if you need specific responses and remove the echo statements if they are making the output harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is test it, then you could use an online tools such as:

- https://ismodpagespeedworking.com/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Type in your domain name or http address, and hit the "Check" button

If you want to test further:

- open Chrome, and open the Developer Tools via menu under Options → More Tools → Developer Tools (Or just use the keyboard shortcut `<CTRL> + <SHIFT> + I`)
- Try and load a web page on the server you just enabled PageSpeed on.

You should see a result like this:

[image: Pagespeed]

Information Source: https://moz.com/ugc/use-googles-pagespeed-module-to-dramatically-increase-the-speed-of-your-website